# What is the correct path to my database when I deploy heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have created a table with SQLAlchemy inside a flask application in this application I implemented a python code to query data in an SQLite database.

```
database = r"C:\\Users\Stuffs\\Flask\\users.db"

def create_connection(db_file):

    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn


def insert_value(conn, column, value):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(" UPDATE users SET %s = %s WHERE id=1;" %(column, value))

def users_insert(column, value):

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:
        insert_value(conn, column, value)
```

On the server side I have a python routine that analyzes the occurrence of an event and when it happens the value of one of the database columns is modified.

- Python code on serve side.

```
if len(classe)>=2:
     i += 1
     users_insert("value_xbr", str(i))
```

About my database I follow videos on youtube where the programmer creates the database with sqlite3 and sqlalchemy, when deploying heroku he gets the link `'postgres://blabla....bla'` and replaces it with the path he had before.

On my local host the project works perfectly. However, when I deployed it to heroku I caught some errors. To deploy on heroku I change the path of the database located on the local host to link to the development database on Heroku.

My problem is just that, what is the correct path to my database when I deploy heroku?

I would also like to know if there is a better way to do this code, i.e. to change the value of a certain column in the database when a specific event occurs that will be evaluated on the server side.

Comment: SQLite is a bad choice for Heroku deployment, as the file lives on the dyno even if you _did_ know the path to it your data would disappear on at least a daily basis: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted-from-the-application.

Comment: The `'postgres://blabla....bla'` string is connection information to a _PostgreSQL_ database. That is a much better choice than SQLite on Heroku, as jonrsharpe has already pointed out. But you can't connect to it using the `sqlite3` module. You'll need a PostgreSQL module like `psycopg2`. And you should use PostgreSQL on your development machine as well. These things aren't drop-in replacements for each other.

Comment: @Chris I have some doubts, I created a database with sqlite3 and SQLAlchemy, but I did some configuration and got the link `'postgres://blabla....bla'`, in this case the database will work as `PostgreSQL` database?  if I connect my database with the `psycopg2` module will my code work?

Comment: My database is working on heroku, only the connection doesn't work. I created the database and did the deployment by watching this video 
 [Deploy Flask App With Database On Heroku For Webhosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiCAIRc0pEI&list=PLhQIPMAaUge0ucQaEet7Rm6YN4wW4MXh1&index=12).